# "Power series" in Cos[n*x] for X coordinate of planetary ellipse

Tags: fitting, trigonometry

Consider the functions below:

```
 
ellipseAreaFromFocus[a_,b_,t_] = a*b*t/2 - Sqrt[a^2-b^2]*b*Sin[t]/2 

(* NOTE: origin is midpoint of two focii, x = semimajor axis *) 

ellipseMA2XY[a_,b_,ma_] := Module[{t}, 
 t = x /. FindRoot[ellipseAreaFromFocus[a,b,x]==a*b*ma/2,{x,0}]; 
 {a*Cos[t], b*Sin[t]} 
];
```

If we sample the first coordinate of `ellipseMA2XY[1.022,1,t]` at 
several points, we can approximate it with a linear combination of `Cos[n*x]`:

```
 
t = Table[{t,ellipseMA2XY[1.022,1,t][[1]]},{t,0,2*Pi,.001}]; 

f[x_] = Fit[t,Table[Cos[n*x],{n,0,6}],x]; 

-0.10545614758232982 + 1.0057258170784746*Cos[x] +  
 0.10248576787806324*Cos[2*x] + 0.01567938482407289*Cos[3*x] +  
 0.0028440630822004482*Cos[4*x] + 0.0005668729202178632*Cos[5*x] +  
 0.00011997552131595974*Cos[6*x]
```

My question: assuming I carried this series to infinity, what's the 
formula for the coefficient of `Cos[n*x]` in terms of `1.022` (or any 
other value I put in there).

The eccentricity of this ellipse is `Sqrt[1-1/1.022^2]` or `0.206372`, and 
the constant term appears to be about `-1/2` of that (it might become exactly `-1/2` in the infinite expansion), but the others leave me 
semi-stumped.

It is known that there's no finite expression for 
`ellipseMA2XY[1.022,1,t][[1]]`, but I'm convinced that an infinite 
expansion in `Cos[n*x]` exists (and is probably well-known)

(I realize I could ask this in math.stackexchange.com, but since I'm 
using Mathematica, I figured I'd try here first)

Comment: Could maybe get a good approximation using a discrete Fourier transform method.

Comment: What you're asking for is the Fourier series of `ellipseMA2XY`. Try `FourierSeries`.

Answer (score 4):

I got nowhere useful with the DCT so I went instead with straight `Fourier`. The idea is take the discrete Fourier transform of the points, use the first as the dc component, sum the rest with the reversal thereof to get cosines from complex exponentials, and only use the first half since we don't want to confuse negative frequencies with high frequencies.

```
fft = Fourier[t[[All, 2]]]/Sqrt[Length[t]];
dc = First[fft];
fftrest = Rest[fft];
fftcos = Re[fftrest + Conjugate[Reverse[fftrest]]];
len = Floor[Length[fftcos]/2]
```

Let's have a look at some of these.

```
dc
fftcos[[1 ;; 10]]

(* -0.1053099823173539 + 0. I

{1.005831877937645, 0.102413921396564, 0.01562846836386967,
0.002813229515042125, 0.0005474867224487756, 0.0001069486252433002,
0.00001716571734559302, -9.589586401412791*10^-7,
-4.036307493988713*10^-6, -4.029977347108143*10^-6} *)
```

They look to be reasonably close to what `Fit` gave, and that is good news of course.

```
Plot[dc + Take[fftcos, len].Table[Cos[n*x], {n, len}], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]